# Есть ли возможность создать клиента-vider(пользователь как программа) для отправки сообщения боту?

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon, viber

Для того чтобы реализовать например клиента в telegram, есть возможность создания аккаунта как программы. Далее пользуемся библиотекой telethon и все прекрасно работает. Вопрос: есть ли аналогичная возможность для мессенджера viber?

Comment: Вопрос не касается создания бота.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно есть - вот [документация официальная](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/python-bot-api/#viber-python-bot-api)

1. Установить библиотеку `pip install viberbot`
2. Импортировать `viberbot.api` в ваш проект
3. Создать бота и получить токен [здесь](https://partners.viber.com/account/create-bot-account)
4. Настроить бота как показано ниже
5. Запустить ваш вебсервер
6. Привязать  webhook

Настройка бота:

```
from viberbot import Api
from viberbot.api.bot_configuration import BotConfiguration

bot_configuration = BotConfiguration(
    name='PythonSampleBot',
    avatar='http://viber.com/avatar.jpg',
    auth_token='YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN_HERE'
)
viber = Api(bot_configuration)
```

Создание сервера (как пример использован фреймворк `Flask`, но вы можете выбрать любой другой)

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/incoming', methods=['POST'])
def incoming():
    logger.debug("received request. post data: {0}".format(request.get_data()))
    # handle the request here
    return Response(status=200)

context = ('server.crt', 'server.key')
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

Привязываем webhook

```
viber.set_webhook('https://mybotwebserver.com:443/')
```

Пример простейшего бота:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from viberbot import Api
from viberbot.api.bot_configuration import BotConfiguration
from viberbot.api.messages import VideoMessage
from viberbot.api.messages.text_message import TextMessage
import logging

from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberConversationStartedRequest
from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberFailedRequest
from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberMessageRequest
from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberSubscribedRequest
from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberUnsubscribedRequest

app = Flask(__name__)
viber = Api(BotConfiguration(
    name='PythonSampleBot',
    avatar='http://site.com/avatar.jpg',
    auth_token='445da6az1s345z78-dazcczb2542zv51a-e0vc5fva17480im9'
))


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def incoming():
    logger.debug("received request. post data: {0}".format(request.get_data()))
    # every viber message is signed, you can verify the signature using this method
    if not viber.verify_signature(request.get_data(), request.headers.get('X-Viber-Content-Signature')):
        return Response(status=403)

    # this library supplies a simple way to receive a request object
    viber_request = viber.parse_request(request.get_data())

    if isinstance(viber_request, ViberMessageRequest):
        message = viber_request.message
        # lets echo back
        viber.send_messages(viber_request.sender.id, [
            message
        ])
    elif isinstance(viber_request, ViberSubscribedRequest):
        viber.send_messages(viber_request.get_user.id, [
            TextMessage(text="thanks for subscribing!")
        ])
    elif isinstance(viber_request, ViberFailedRequest):
        logger.warn("client failed receiving message. failure: {0}".format(viber_request))

    return Response(status=200)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = ('server.crt', 'server.key')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

Comment: вот мне как раз бот и не нужен, я хочу сам как пользователь автоматически отправлять боту сообщение. То есть я(пользователь-программа) отпраляю боту сообщение с помощью программы.